# unshare mount namespace not working as expected

Tags: c, linux

When I call the Linux system function unshare(CLONE_NEWNS), it returns 0 indicating success.  But, it doesn't seem to work as I was expecting.
Specifically when I then add a new mount such as a tmpfs one, it is globally visible.  Therefore it is in fact not a private mount namespace as expected.

Here is an example program that demonstrates the issue.  Compile this up and run it in one terminal.  Then open another terminal and check if the path written by the example program is visible.  It shouldn't be but is.  It is behaving as though the unshare call did nothing. What I was expecting was that from that moment on, any subsequent mounts performed by this program will not be visible to other processes.

```
/* Run this program as root.  As mount and unshare requires higher privileges. */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create a temporary directory at /tmp/unshare
    mkdir("/tmp/unshare", S_IRWXG);
    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) == -1)
        errExit("unshare");

    if (mount("none", "/tmp/unshare", "tmpfs", 0, "mode=0700") == -1)
        errExit("unshare");

    FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/unshare/test", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "This file should not be seen by other processes right?\n");
    fclose(fp);

    // Pause
    printf("Now open another shell.  As the root user, verify the file /tmp/unshare/test is not seen\n.Press enter end finish\n");
    char c = getchar();

    if (umount("/tmp/unshare") == -1)
        errExit("umount");
}
```

I should point out that the mount manpage suggests this should work.  Specifically section labeled "Per-process namespaces".

i.e.

```
A process can obtain a private mount namespace if ... 
it calls unshare(2)  with  the  CLONE_NEWNS  flag,  which
causes  the  caller's  mount  namespace to obtain a private copy of the
namespace that it was previously sharing with other processes, so  that
future  mounts  and  unmounts by the caller are invisible to other pro‐
cesses (except child processes that the  caller  subsequently  creates)
and vice versa.
```

If you use the unshare terminal command, it works.  But that also forks another process.  But the man page suggests there is no need to fork or clone when using the unshare system call.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Dude, unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) is a C call !  this is using the linux API.  What do you mean off topic?  I need this to work from C.

Comment: How are you mounting the filesystem? From the same program or from your shell after your program exits?

Comment: From the program using the mount systemcall.  No shell.

Comment: Can you include the source code of a short program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'll have to knock something up separate.  Hold on.

Comment: Try using `MS_PRIVATE` as the third parameter to `mount`.

Comment: @n.m. - invalid argument.  Apparently MS_PRIVATE is the default.

Comment: @n.m - the manpage doesn't suggest MS_PRIVATE is actually an available option.  But I see it mentioned in other man page versions on the web for mount(2).  Odd.  This is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Weird, your program works on my machine (Gentoo). Maybe Ubuntu doesn't implement the mount namespaces? Also my initial comment was incorrect, you have to call `mount`1 twice --- once with 0 flags and after the first one succeeds, with MS_PRIVATE (you can only modify propagation flags on existing mount points). Though on my machine it works with no MS_PRIVATE. Obviously this won't help in your case, as the mount point is already seen by other processes.

Comment: strace your `unshare` command and see which syscalls it calls.

Comment: @n.m. - I did the strace and discovered the MS_PRIVATE thing.  Oddly, it still doesn't work.  I read a comment that although MS_PRIVATE is meant to be the default, Ubuntu 16.04 now uses systemd which changes that default to shared.  So it could be a systemd thing.  Anyway, it should work in theory because otherwise I wouldn't expect docker would work and it does.  Unless they of course use the clone call.  Might try that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After running strace I found the answer.

```
\> strace unmount -m true
...
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)                    = 0
mount("none", "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL) = 0
execve("/home/matt/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/true", ["true"], [/* 29 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```

Note the mount following the unshare.  This mount call would appear to recursively mark all subsequent changes to mounts as private.  And looking at this sandbox code: https://github.com/swetland/mkbox
The author is doing just that also.

So here is the working version.

```
/* Run this program as root.  As mount and unshare requires higher privileges. */

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while (0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create a temporary directory at /tmp/unshare
    mkdir("/tmp/unshare", S_IRWXG);
    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_FS | CLONE_THREAD) == -1)
        errExit("unshare");

    /* ensure that changes to our mount namespace do not "leak" to
     * outside namespaces (what mount --make-rprivate / does)
     */
    if (mount("none", "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("mount1");

    if (mount("none", "/tmp/unshare", "tmpfs", 0, NULL) == -1)
        errExit("mount2");

    // if (mount("none", "/tmp/unshare", NULL, MS_PRIVATE, NULL) == -1)
    //  errExit("mount2");

    FILE* fp = fopen("/tmp/unshare/test", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "This file should not be seen\n");
    fclose(fp);

    // Pause
    printf("Now open another shell.  As the root user, verify the file /tmp/unshare/test is not seen\n.Press enter end finish\n");
    char c = getchar();

    if (umount("/tmp/unshare") == -1)
        errExit("umount");
}
```

Comment: Wait! If we have to do `mount --make-rprivate /` by our own, why do we need  `unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)`??? `CLONE_NEWNS` is supposed to isolate mount/umount operations in different mount namespaces, right? But in your example, it is done by `mount --make-rprivate /`, so what is effect of `CLONE_NEWNS` at all?

Comment: @Eric It's probably not obvious but as far as I know here's the thing. CLONE_NEWNS does clone the parent NS into an isolated one. In other words, you're in a copy of the NS but changes are isolated. So if your parent / was mounted with MS_PRIVATE the remount pass wouldn't be necessary. As the documentation on pivot_root says, it cannot be used on a MS_SHARED mount. So MS_PRIVATE isn't the only flag that could be used as long as it's not MS_SHARED.

Comment: THANKS! The remount of / (+ MS_REC) to MS_PRIVATE was the key after hours of debugging why pivot_root() didn't work in my new mountns or unmounting my pc's mounts after cleanup (making me restart the pc since everything stopped working)!

This should be recommended by default when unsharing the mntns! Such a BOOBIE TRAP. Didn't even notice it when strace'ing unshare earlier.