# Reshare CLONE_NEWNS after unshare

Tags: linux, namespaces

I have part of applicatoin which unshare CLONE_NEWNS to have private mount namespace in the process. Code is similar to [unshare code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580252/3218777).

How to reverse effect of this unshare? I want to share the parent namespace again.

Answer (score 0):

Get the original namespace fd before calling `unshare()`, then, after `unshare()`, you can switch back by calling `setns()`. If the original namespace is not altered by current process or by its parent process, you don't even need to get the fd beforeahead, you can get it anytime by open `/proc/$ppid/ns/mnt` (corresponding with your `CLONE_NEWNS`)